# Python pandas concat function gives a dataframe with wrong dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am having trouble concatenating two dataframes. Both are of shape (8250x1) yet, if I concatenate the two, I somehow end up with a 13783x2 dataframe. The 'new' entries are filled with NaN and I have no idea why.

Here's my code:

```
def performance(fitted, actual):
  # create one dataframe with fitted and actual values together
  if isinstance(actual,pd.DataFrame):
    actual.rename(columns={actual.columns[0]:'LGL_actual'}, inplace=True)
  else:
    actual = pd.DataFrame(actual.to_list(), columns = ['LGL_actual'])

  if isinstance(fitted,pd.DataFrame):
    fitted.rename(columns={fitted.columns[0]:'LGL_fitted'}, inplace=True)
  else:
    fitted = pd.DataFrame(fitted.to_list(), columns = ['LGL_fitted'])

  df = pd.concat([fitted, actual], axis=1)
  y_actual = df['LGL_actual']
  y_fitted = df['LGL_fitted']
  y_mean = np.mean(y_actual)
  SST = np.sum((y_actual - y_mean)** 2)
  SSR = np.sum((y_fitted - y_mean)** 2)
  R2 = SSR/SST

 # calculate mean squared error (MSE)
  MSE = np.mean((y_actual - y_fitted) ** 2)
  return R2, MSE, SST, SSR, df
```

This returns as output for df (the concatenated dataframes):

```
print(df)
       
       LGL_fitted  LGL_actual
0      1.842137e-09         NaN
1      2.845566e-01         NaN
2      3.529837e-01         NaN
3      4.409625e-12    0.404955
4      6.357694e-02         NaN
...             ...         ...
22818           NaN    0.039901
16115           NaN    0.487271
10802           NaN    0.030231
12899           NaN    0.000000
18149           NaN    0.095125

[13783 rows x 2 columns]
```

Any idea why this might be the case? I know for sure the two entries are of shape (8250x1) but I have no idea where the extra entries come from. I am looking to get a new matrix with dimensions (8250x2) Thanks in advance!

I have already tried checking the sizes and printing the shape of the individual dataframes, but they are correct...

Comment: Hello Jelle, please provide a minimal sample for actual and fitted so that we may reproduce the issue. A first guess would be that they have different indices which concat tries to respect.

Comment: Try to add argument `ignore_index=True` to the `concat` call.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the concatenated dataframe, the indexes are mixed. Before concat on each dataframe make sure you do `fitted = fitted.reset_index(drop=True)` and same for the `actual` dataframe and re-try.

For example:
I created these 2 dataframes, you will see that the indexes are different for both and when we concatenate there is NaN's appearing for cases where there is no value at the index.

```
student_dict1 = {'Marks 1': [85.10, 77.80, 91.54]}
student_dict2 = {'Marks 2': [111.10, 222.80, 333.54]}
# create DataFrame from dict
student_df1 = pd.DataFrame(student_dict1)
student_df2 = pd.DataFrame(student_dict2)
# set wrong index on purpose
student_df1.index = [0, 7, 2]
student_df2.index = [0, 1, 2]
# REMOVE .reset_index(drop=True) and you will get the same problem you are facing
student_df1 = student_df1.reset_index(drop=True)
student_df2 = student_df2.reset_index(drop=True)

df = pd.concat([student_df1, student_df2], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Without `.reset_index(drop=True)`

```
   Marks 1  Marks 2
0    85.10   111.10
7    77.80      NaN
2    91.54   333.54
1      NaN   222.80
```

With `.reset_index(drop=True)`

```
   Marks 1  Marks 2
0    85.10   111.10
1    77.80   222.80
2    91.54   333.54
```

Comment: _"the indexes are mixed"_: to be more precise, "the indices are _aligned_".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually it did end up having the same indices because I could see that when I took the two dataframes out of the function. Not sure why it didn't match them correct but thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `merge` function instead of `concat`

```
def performance(fitted, actual):
# create one dataframe with fitted and actual values together
if isinstance(actual, pd.DataFrame):
    actual.rename(columns={actual.columns[0]: 'LGL_actual'}, inplace=True)
else:
    actual = pd.DataFrame(actual.to_list(), columns=['LGL_actual'])

if isinstance(fitted, pd.DataFrame):
    fitted.rename(columns={fitted.columns[0]: 'LGL_fitted'}, inplace=True)
else:
    fitted = pd.DataFrame(fitted.to_list(), columns=['LGL_fitted'])

df = pd.merge(fitted, actual, left_index=True, right_index=True) # <- here
y_actual = df['LGL_actual']
y_fitted = df['LGL_fitted']
y_mean = np.mean(y_actual)
SST = np.sum((y_actual - y_mean) ** 2)
SSR = np.sum((y_fitted - y_mean) ** 2)
R2 = SSR / SST

# calculate mean squared error (MSE)
MSE = np.mean((y_actual - y_fitted) ** 2)
return R2, MSE, SST, SSR, df
```

Comment: Imho that won't work: the resulting dataframe will only contain rows corresponding to indices that are present in _both_ dataframes (because you merge on the indices and `how` is `'inner'` by default). The question asks for a solution that is indifferent to indices.